# Send Mass E-mail PHPMAILER through G-Suite

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, google-workspace

So i have the following code:

```
  while(list($i, $data_subscriber) = each($subscriber)) {

     $email_counter = $i + 1;
     echo ($email_counter).') '.$data_subscriber->field_1.' '.$data_subscriber->field_2.' - '.$data_subscriber->email.''."\n";
     flush();

     $language = $data_subscriber->lang;

     $body_mail = include($template_send_newsletter);

     $first_name_idx = $data_subscriber->field_1;
     $last_name_idx = $data_subscriber->field_2;

     if (mail_send(strtolower($data_subscriber->email),
                   ( IsSet($first_name_idx) && IsSet($last_name_idx) ? $first_name_idx.' '.$last_name_idx : $data_subscriber->email ),
                   $site_admin,
                   $site_name,
                   'Newsletter ['.date('d/m/Y', time()).']',
                   true,
                   $body_mail,
                   NULL,
                   false)) {

       reset($data_subscriber->newsletter_item);
       unset($log_detail);
       $log_detail = "";
       while(list($j, $list_of_news_to_send) = each($data_subscriber->newsletter_item)) {
         $log_detail = ( IsSet($list_of_news_to_send->title) ? $list_of_news_to_send->title."\n" : '');
         $log_detail = ( IsSet($list_of_news_to_send->subtitle) ? $list_of_news_to_send->subtitle."\n" : '');
         $log_detail = ( IsSet($list_of_news_to_send->creation_date) ? $list_of_news_to_send->creation_date."\n" : '');
         $log_detail = "\n";
       } /* end while */

       write_newsletter_detail($data_subscriber->id_subscription,
                               $data_subscriber->email,
                               'Y',
                               $log_detail);
     }
     else {
       write_newsletter_detail($data_subscriber->id_subscription,
                               $data_subscriber->email,
                               'N',
                               NULL);
     } /* end if mail_send */

   } /* end while */
```

And the following function

```
function mail_send($rcpt_to,           
                   $to_name,                 
                   $mail_from,                
                   $from_name,                
                   $subject,          
                   $isHTML = true,            
                   $body,                     
                   $attachment = NULL,        
                   $direct_delivery = false,
                   $reply_to = NULL){

    $mail = new PHPmailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "mail@domain.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    $mail->Timeout = 3600;
    $mail->addAddress(trim($rcpt_to), trim($to_name));
    $mail->setFrom($mail_from,$from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;

    if ($isHTML) {
      $mail->IsHTML(true);
      $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($mail->Body);
    } 
    if (IsSet($attachment)) {
      $mail->AddAttachment($attachment['tmp_name'], $attachment['name']);
    }
    if (IsSet($reply_to)) {
      $mail->AddReplyTo($reply_to);
    }
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
  }
```

I am using PHPMailer to send multiple e-mails using gmail SMTP server.
I have 4 files containing different but almost the same code to send newsletter.
One of my files is sending all the emails to ( ~60 recipients )
The other 3 files, each of them needs to send one email to ~600 recipients.
Problem occures here, half of the e-mails are sent the other are not.
If I run the script but this time for fewer recipients witch didn't recieved the e-mail first time, it's sending.

I'm using GMAIL with my own domain. So i'm not exceeding any limit.

What may cause this problem ? Any ideas ? Thank you.

UPDATE**

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 454 4.7.0 Too many login attempts, please try again later. e11sm950198edd.68 - gsmtp
```

After some emails that are sent i recieve this error. Any ideas why ?

UPDATE***

```
  $mail = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true; // SMTP connection will not close after each email sent, reduces SMTP overhead
  $mail->Port = 465;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->Username = "domain@domain.com";
  $mail->Password = "password";
  $mail->setFrom($site_noreply, $site_name);
  $subjectnewsletter = 'Newsletter ['.date('d/m/Y', time()).']';
  $mail->Subject = $subjectnewsletter;
  $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

  reset($subscriber);
  while(list($i, $data_subscriber) = each($subscriber)) {
   $email_counter = $i + 1;
   echo ($email_counter).') '.$data_subscriber->field_1.' '.$data_subscriber->field_2.' - '.$data_subscriber->email.''."\n";
   flush();
   $language = $data_subscriber->lang;
   $first_name_idx = $data_subscriber->field_1;
   $last_name_idx = $data_subscriber->field_2;
   $fullname = $first_name_idx.' '.$last_name_idx;

   $bodymail = include($template_send_newsletter);
   $mail->msgHTML($bodymail);
   $mail->addAddress($data_subscriber->email, $fullname);
   reset($data_subscriber->newsletter_item);
   unset($log_detail);
   $log_detail = "";
   while(list($j, $list_of_news_to_send) = each($data_subscriber->newsletter_item)) {
     $log_detail = ( IsSet($list_of_news_to_send->title) ? $list_of_news_to_send->title."\n" : '');
     $log_detail = ( IsSet($list_of_news_to_send->subtitle) ? $list_of_news_to_send->subtitle."\n" : '');
     $log_detail = ( IsSet($list_of_news_to_send->creation_date) ? $list_of_news_to_send->creation_date."\n" : '');
     $log_detail = "\n";
   } /* end while */
   if (!$mail->send()) {
     write_newsletter_detail($data_subscriber->id_subscription,
                             $data_subscriber->email,
                             'N',
                             NULL);
       echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
       break; //Abandon sending
   } else {

     write_newsletter_detail($data_subscriber->id_subscription,
                             $data_subscriber->email,
                             'Y',
                             $log_detail);
       echo "Message sent";
   }
   $mail->clearAddresses();
   $mail->clearAttachments();
  } /* end while */
```

I managed to change my code so it's not connect to the smtp server every e-mail.
But now after it sends 93 emails i get the follosing error:

```
SMTP server error: MAIL FROM command failed
```

Comment: Perhaps a rate-limit to stop you spamming people?

Comment: "I'm using GMAIL with my own domain. So i'm not exceeding any limit." There are still limits. https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en Use a real newsletter system.

Comment: well error clearly says what's wrong, you re-login with every email

Comment: @Peter any idea how can i login just once ?

Comment: @AlexF. Sure. Set up the `$mail = new PHPmailer;` stuff *outside* the loop.

Comment: @ceejayoz i mange to do in that way but i still get an error after it sends 93 emails.

Comment: Well, send through a system like Sendgrid or AWS SES that's **intended** for bulk emails, then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) that uses more than one connection and it already setup to respect limits of the servers you're connecting to. At this point you're attempting to exceed the limits of the server you're connecting to and companies like [Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?hl=en) frown on too many connections or using their mail servers for broadcasts.

Look for a [mail sending service](https://www.google.com/search?q=mail%20sending%20service&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) if your numbers are modest, or consider purchasing and hosting an MTA if you send a considerable amount of email.

Comment: Yes i know, but as I use G-Suite E-mail service for sending email i have a total of 2000 messages per day. My scripts are sending around 1400-1500 messages a day. So theoretically i should be able to send them.

Comment: Are you setting `$site_noreply` and `$side_name`, and is `$site_noreply` a valid email address, meaning a bounced email can go there and is retrievable? Also I've updated your question to indicate that you are using gsuite. Some people send emails through Google as a mail sending service using their gmail accounts and hit the limits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SMTP relay](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491) configuration which allow you to send email from your server with any of your email domain address.